# Scipy.linalg matrix multiplication implementation, all in C or some in Fortran?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, matrix-multiplication

I have recently been researching to find out how the multiplications on (mainly sparse) matrices are implemented in this optimum way in python library scipy.linalg I Know from [here](https://www.scipy.org/scipylib/faq.html#how-can-scipy-be-fast-if-it-is-written-in-an-interpreted-language-like-python) that mostly the algorithms are the wrappings of some Fortran or C libraries.

My question is how could I know there are any multiplication methods in Scipy that are actually written inside python itself? I am also not very sure how it works with Numpy matrix multiplications.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I suggest you to read asking [guidelines of Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `scipy.sparse` has its own multiplication code (elementwise and matrix), separate from the numpy array operations.  All use compiled code where possible.  Some is custom `c`, some `cython`, and some libraries like `BLAS`.

Comment: @hpaulj How can I know specifically in which language, for example, `matvec` or `rmatvec` in `scipy.linalg` are implemented? (Here my concern is basically to know how the algorithm is handling the multiplication **optimally** and if that is at all possible **purely in python** without using wrapped code from different high level languages)

Comment: We don't know, and we usually don't care.  Why are you concerned about this?  Are you trying to recreate some calculations in your own package or language?  We have to trust that the `numpy` developers have chosen the optimal approach to these calculations.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you very much for you reply. It actually is a part of my research to find out how these multiplications are optimized in python, and I went through all the documentations (including Github) but couldn't get a concrete answer. I know most of them are optimized using BLAS but it is not mentioned which ones or to which extent.

Comment: `np.show_config()` shows the available libraries on your machine.  This depends on what's been downloaded, and how the `numpy/scipy` was compiled and linked.  But beyond that digging through `numpy/scipy` `c` code is not a trivial task.  There's a lot of preprocessing.

Comment: Also look at github issues and pull requests.  `matmul` has undergone a lot of development in recent years.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix multiplication being computationally heavy is not done typically in Python. A typical matrix multiplication will be O(n^3), so Numpy and Scipy both use C based matrix multiplications and use wrappers to bring that in Python.

Comment: Thank you for you fast response.

Comment: But I was wondering if there is a source that shows which operation is implemented in which language, weather it's C or Fortran. And if there are more that one implementation of the same operation (matrix multiplications, e.g. matvec in Scipy) which one is assigned to which class or method?